# When transferring Ether, who needs to be in sync with the blockchain?

Tags: transactions, synchronization

A transfers ETH to B: who needs to be in sync with the blockchain?
My comprehension is that A only needs to be sync, is that correct ?

Comment: I'm tempted to say it's possible to sign transactions without any synced client on both sides cause the network decides whether the transaction is valid. But I leave the answer to the experts.

Comment: I think you may be correct.  You can sign transactions offline.  Whether they are accepted is up to the network

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither of the clients need to be in sync to get the transaction through.

For a transaction to be valid you only need to have enough funds on the sender balance, use the correct nonce for the sender account (that you could retrieve from a block explorer for example) and sign the entire thing with the sender's private key. If you inject just a transaction into the network, it will happily accept and process it.

Comment: ok that's the nonce part I was missing...thanks it's very clear

Comment: is there anyway to know if the current `geth` instance is in sync with the network so that it will use a correct nonce?

Comment: (and I meant, programmatically, via API)

Answer (score 5):

Péter provides the answer to the general question about transactions.

In **practical terms**, when using a wallet, **a sender of Ether needs to be in sync**, otherwise the wallet may generate an invalid transaction that will never be processed.

For example, a wallet that's not synced (and unaware of Ether the sender may have already spent) might use a wrong nonce or try to send more Ether than what the sender actually has.

Comment: that's effectively an important point, there is theory and there is practice.

Comment: But it's not dangerous, right? It just won't work occasionally, possibly, if the wallet is not in sync. So we can try and the sky won't fall down on us.

Comment: @Vesa not dangerous because you can't overdraw and get charged fees like a bank would do; but it could be inconvenient if you make many payments and find out that 90% of them didn't work because you didn't have the actual funds: you'd probably have to redo those failed payments again.

Comment: Right, yeah. Inconvenient but not unsafe, then.