# How to Keep Geth Always Up-To-Date?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, ropsten, geth-debugging

It kind of suck if every time we want to test our smart contract, we need to wait until our testnet blockchain is synced up.

How do you usually keep it up-to-date?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21439/writing-contracts-without-fully-syncing-blockchain might be of interest to you, too.

Comment: Thanks @lungj. I've tried deploying a simpler version of smart contract without syncing the entire blockchain, but I'd think that wouldn't work if you want to build more complicated smart contract. I'm using truffle framework

Answer (score 1):

Keep a geth instance running and connected to the network (testnet in this case), it synchronise automatically.